# Visual Studioで特定の条件でラムダ式がビルドエラーを起こす

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

Visual Studio Community 2015でビルドしたところ下記のようなエラーが出ました。

[wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) でclang、gccを使ってビルドした限りではエラーは出ませんでした。
なぜVisual Studioでだけエラーが出るのか教えてください。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
error C3493: 既定のキャプチャ モードが指定されていないため、'value' を暗黙的にキャプチャできません
```

**ソースコード**

```
#include <forward_list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    []{
        forward_list<int> list;
        int value;
        auto &ref = list;
        list.remove_if(
            [](const remove_reference_t<decltype(ref)>::value_type &value)
            { return value < 0; });
    }();
}
```

Comment: 外側の`int value;`を使っていないのは意図的ですか？内側ラムダの引数`value`のみが参照されています。

Comment: 外側のint value;は`const remove_reference_t<decltype(ref)>::value_type &この部分`と同様の名前の変数が合った場合のみエラーが出たので、エラーが出ることの再現のためだけに使っています。

Comment: コード自体には問題はないと思われるのでたぶんVisual Studioのバグでしょう。Visual Studioは以前からバグがgcc,clangに比べてかなり多く、こういった現象は珍しいことではありません。[ここ](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback)で`lambda`を検索するといくつかバグ報告があります。

Comment: `const remove_reference_t<decltype(ref)>::value_type &`を`const auto&`にするだけでも、コンパイルできるようになりますね。